# Playground not showing results

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I've got a Mac mini (early 2009) 2GB RAM. 
Clean installed El Capitan. Xcode 7.3

Created playground (default) but no results showing.

Are there hardware requirements for playground?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details? What results do you expect to see, what do you see?

Comment: I see nothing. The default playground doesn't produce anything.

Comment: @George Asda did you add any device in simulator?

Comment: Yes. There is a device in the sim.

Answer (score 0):

Show the Debug area and Execute Playground to see resuls
[image: Show the Debug Area]
[image: Execute Playground]

Comment: I get and endless spinning "running". Nothing is shown... Left for an hour no errors or crashes

Comment: Bad installation? Did you try to download and install XCode again?

Comment: Yes. Just did that. Nothing.

Comment: For those who still need it : )Try to inject playground code into some VC, I do get occasionally compiler error in PG using Xcode 8.1, some kind of segmentation error which doesn't exist in a real project, at least after rebuilding of the project.